# How do you adjust so the text in the columns become evenly spaced and aligned?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I am trying to createa an error table as below - I referenced this post [Error in Tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330517/error-in-tables)

I tried editing it to my case, but I'm not able to align the error metric with the values associated to it. See the picture below:

[image]

I would like all the text in table to aligned to the left, and also that the text in the columns are aligned, so for instance PICP and 0.96523 and 0.95965 should be aligned.

How can I do this?

```
\begin{table}[ht] 
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{@{} c c S[table-format=-2.3] 
                      c S[table-format=-2.2] @{}} 
 \toprule
 Data & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Train} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Test} \\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
 & PICP & NMPIL & PICP & NMPIL\\
 \midrule
  firstDifference & 0.96523  & 0.12232 & 0.96814  & 0.14074 \\
  Box Cox & 0.95965   & 0.31045 & 0.96245  & 0.31382 \\
 
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{highres} Prediction interval results for GP Models}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{4}{S[table-format=1.5]} @{}} ` should get you closer to the expected output.

Comment: @leandriis that gives me a long list of "Package array Error: Illegal pream-token"

Comment: However, the table is adjusted so it looks kind of good. Not sure why it works with all the error messaes? @leandriis

Comment: I'm sorry. I spotted a mistake in my imports (used one file to test table and then input it in my real document). Thank you for your help @leandriis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with `tabularray` and its `siunitx` and `booktabs` libraries.

Please note that with the option `guard` you don't have to worry anymore about headers used with `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-digits=false}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]\centering 
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={l*{4}{S[table-format=1.5]}},% see leandris's comment
    cell{1}{2,4}={c=2}{c},
    row{1,2} = {guard}
    }
    \toprule
    Data & Train & & Test &\\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-3}\cmidrule[l]{4-5}
    & PICP & NMPIL & PICP & NMPIL\\
    \midrule
    firstDifference & 0.96523 & 0.12232 & 0.96814 & 0.14074 \\
    Box Cox & 0.95965 & 0.31045 & 0.96245 & 0.31382 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{\label{highres} Prediction interval results for GP Models}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]